# Set Activity- GridView as gallery in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-manifest, intentfilter

I want to make a custom gallery Android app. I coded `MyActivity.java` as `GridView` showing all images of the phone and its working.

I have searched but results only contain to make  custom gallery.
What permission should be used in `AndroidManifest.xml` or any other thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: i am asking how to set activity as gallery i have already made that activity custom gallery using gridview